# How to generate OTP & verify from using SAP UI5?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, netweaver

**I want to generate OTP & verify using SAP UI5. Just like Bank payment gateway.**

**Scenario**:

> Suppose User enter UI5 application. One pop will come with combobox &
>   one input field. ComboBox will contain dropdown of Mobile Nmber. User
>   will select One mobile number. Once he will select mobile number, one
>   sms should trigger to that number with OTP. Post that he will enter
>   OTP in Input filed and if it is correct then only user should allow to
>   do further operations on application

This is for SAP UI5 Custom Application. I tried using some third party sms gateway but unable to get SMS with OTP.

Comment: You need to share more details about your scenario. Where did you send sms? In backend or ui? Did you get sms?

Comment: Suppose User enter UI5 application. One pop will come with combobox & one input field. ComboBox will contain dropdown of Mobile Nmber. User will select One mobile number. Once he will select mobile number, one sms should trigger to that number with OTP. Post that he will enter OTP in Input filed and if it is correct then only user should allow to do further operations on application. tried using some third party sms gateway but unable to get SMS with OTP.

Comment: Your problem is not related with ui5. You need to fix sms provider integration firstly. You need to ask sms provider for reason. May be there is no balance in your account, number format not correct or country not supported. Check sms provider management web panel for balance and error logs.